# 3D scatter plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm fairly new to Matlab and would appreciate some help. I'm trying to graph a scatter plot of a function. Later on I'm going to fit other functions to this data and plot that on the same figure. But what I have so far plots the markers all in one plane, which isn't what I want. The function is 2D, the graph should be 3D. How do I get this?

Here's what I've been trying so far. There's some other code before this that generates different values for f(i,j) given different parameters, so when I implement the code I get a series of figures.

```
for i=1:somenumber
    for j=1:somenumber
        f(i,j)=etc.
    end
end

figure;
x=1:somenumber;
plot3(x,f,x,'rs');
hold on;
```

Comment: @John: 3D plots are almost always horrible.  Things at the back are often obscured, and you have perspective issues to mislead you.  Try using colour or marker type to encode the third dimension instead.

Comment: @Richie Cotton: Color can be as misleading if not more. A static 3D plot, especially if there's no shading to help you, is difficult to interpret, I agree, but if you rotate it, it can show you patterns and functional relationships that are otherwise not accessible.

Comment: @Jonas: OK, point taken.  There are a few cases when 3D is useful, especially interactively, but I stand by my comment that often 2D alternatives are clearer.

Answer (score 2):

See my comment on why you likely don't want to do this, but the general way of plotting in 3D is

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:5;
[X Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = X.^2 + 2 .* Y;      % in general, Z = f(X, Y)
plot3(X, Y, Z, '+')
```

Comment: It looks good; I plotted it here https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/3d-scatter-plot

Answer (score 1):

Here is an avenue worth exploring:

```
nSamples = nX * nY;
xValues  = zeros( nSamples, 1 );
yValues  = zeros( nSamples, 1 );
zValues  = zeros( nSamples, 1 );

iSample = 0;
for iX = 1:nX
   for iY = 1:nY
      iSample = iSample + 1;

      xValues( iSample ) = iX;
      yValues( iSample ) = iY;
      zValues( iSample ) = someFunction( iX, iY );

   end
end

figure;
plot3( xValues(:), yValues(:), zValues(:), 'r.' );
```

This should make it easy to add noise to any or all of x, y or z to test your function fitting algorithm.