# generateing a 3 dimensional scatter plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

Consider the following example:

```
x1 = 13 + 6.*rand(100,1);
x2 = x1.*0.7;
x3 = (x2 + 6).*1.2;

figure(1);
plot(x1);hold on;plot(x2);hold on;plot(x3,'--r');

figure(2);
subplot(311);
scatter(x1,x2);
subplot(312);
scatter(x1,x3);
subplot(313);
scatter(x2,x3);
```

Here I have 3 vectors that are highly correlated. Is it possible in Matlab to generate one scatter plot that contains all of the information, i.e. a scatter plot that shows the relationship between `x1` and `x2`; `x2` and `x3`; `x1` and `x3`, possibly a 3d scatter plot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [3D scatter plots in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155343/3d-scatter-plots-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scatter3(x1,x2,x3)
```

See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html for more details

Comment: `plot3(x1,x2,x3,'.')` would be equally valid

Comment: @LuisMendo - works well! https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/3-dimensional-scatter-plot